# Type hinting confusion

Tags: php, php-7, type-hinting

I've recently learned about new type hinting features in php.

First:

```
public function setSomething(Foo $bar):void
```

And also:

```
public function getSomething():Foo
```

Today I came across this:

```
public /*int*/ doSomething()
```

What is this new type hinting? I cannot seem to figure out what this is?

Comment: its just a comment, nothing important

Comment: types can be declared next to variables, as you shown in the first example, or in comment block above the method.

Comment: only works in PHP 7 though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go step-by-step:

1. `public function setSomething(Foo $bar):void`

Here `Foo` is hint that tells $bar must be instance of `Foo` class.
`void` tells that function must return nothing

2. `public function getSomething():Foo`

Here `Foo` hints that function must return instance of `Foo` class

3. `public /*int*/ doSomething()`

In this case actually no one type-hint is used. `/*int*/` is just a comment. I guess somebody left when type-hinting in php was not available.

You can read more in documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Answer (score 0):

Think the other answers cover the main idea that the last version is purely a comment, but there are times when comments are a bit more than comments...

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @return int
 */
public function get ( string $key ) {
```

This is a very trimmed down docblock which is used for producing documentation from code, but also works in various IDE's to help type hint any time you reference the code.

In this comment the return type is specified as int- but the code adds no restriction to this.